# server variable path_info get value that is true but not visible on browser

Tags: iis, redirect, asp-classic

when the user gets to `http://www.domain.com/index.asp`
i need it to redirect him to `http://www.domain.com`

on that server i don't have Isapi (YET) so i want to do it in the `index.asp` page

i check for the
`Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO")` it will always return the `/index.asp` even when it is not in the url of the browser

so what is the solution, in iis or in the code (without isapi rewrite) to redirect the user from the index.asp to only the domain?

Comment: If `index.asp` is defined as the default page, you'll get into infinite loop. First define via IIS different default page.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
response.redirect "."
```